# Docker for chronograf does not start (bin adress already in use)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, influxdb, chronograf

I have installed influxdb and chronograf without success, so I have decided to install them using docker containers. The thing is that when I start chronograf's container, I receive this error message:

sudo docker start chronograf
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint chronograf (): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:8888: bind: address already in use
Error: failed to start containers: chronograf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that another process is using the same port. Check which one using:

`sudo netstat -pna | grep <port>`

Then, kill that process:

`sudo kill <number>`